# How Big is my Wheel Circumference?

Tags: wheels

I'm very new to road biking and struggling to set up my cycle computer on my Triban 500 SE.. Manufacturing Info about bike here :

http://www.decathlon.co.uk/triban-500-se-road-bike-black-id_8306187.html#anchor_ComponentProductTechnicalInformation

To confirm they are 650 tyres which are 23mm wide.

My question is about wheel circumference which I need to be converted into mm. Does anybody know or understand how to work this out?...

Note : I am almost positive this is a very noob question.. However, saying that there is little information about this on the web so an answer that explains how they got to it would be appreciated and would definitely help future newbies!

Comment: 3.14159268 times the diameter.

Comment: (The diameter is roughly 571 + 2 * 23, or 617.  Times pi is 1938.)

Comment: (A "650" rim is also known as a 26" rim, but the actual rim diameter is 571.  The 23mm tire will approximately describe a 23mm circle, so add 23 twice to account for the tire on the rim.  And diameter times pi = circumference.)

Comment: (And there's a cheat sheet of sorts at http://sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html)

Comment: (Of course, the other thing you can do is simply measure how far the bike travels in one full revolution of the wheel)

Comment: Draw a mark on the floor, set the valve over the mark, roll forward until the valve is down again. Measure the distance.